# Parse PFQuery whereKey:notEqualTo is not working for PFUser objects

Tags: ios, debugging, parse-platform, crash, pfquery

I think this is a bug in Parse, but I don't know where to report it.

I'm using Parse with Swift. I have a `PFQueryTableViewController`.

In my `queryForTable` function, I **CAN** use this following query just fine:

```
query.whereKey(kHWActivityFromUserKey, equalTo: User.currentUser())
```

However, when I change `equalTo` to `notEqualTo`, like this:

```
query.whereKey(kHWActivityFromUserKey, notEqualTo: User.currentUser())
```

... then the table stays blank and just does nothing. (It does not even show empty rows.)

I tried to figure out what was going on, so I took that query and I called `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` on it manually, to look at the `objects` and `error` inside the block. Surprisingly, the block was never called!

So then I ran the query on the main thread, like this:

```
    var error = NSErrorPointer()
    var objects = query.findObjects(error)
```

When I ran this, my whole app crashed with the following exception:

```
2015-02-11 13:26:45.339 HDWR[18996:3057150] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Couldn't create cache key from 
<PFUser: 0x7f8e885de7c0, objectId: X7lSc1Gajm, localId: (null)> {
...
```

So I think there is a bug related to caching whenever I use `whereKey:notEqualTo` with a `PFObject`.

I've also tried using the `objectId` string in the query instead, like this:

```
    query.whereKey(kHWActivityFromUserKey, notEqualTo: User.currentUser().objectId)
```

But then Parse just gives me a pointer error:

```
2015-02-11 13:45:46.550 HDWR[19708:3069545] 
Error: pointer field fromUser needs a pointer value (Code: 102, Version: 1.6.0)
```

How can I report this bug to Parse? Or do you have any idea for a workaround? We kind of need to have this logic in our app.

Comment: Parse provides a channel for reporting bugs via their Help page: https://parse.com/help

Comment: Could you show your code in findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock?
Do you pass other options/params to the query?

Comment: Thanks @HectorRamos, I've posted the bug there.

Comment: @IAmDav - It was just a regular `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` call, no other options or params. The query also had a limit of 1000, was ordered by createdAt, and had a cache policy of `kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork`

Comment: I have the same problem with the php-sdk :( notEqualTo gives blank results when using a pointer

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Parse iOS SDK, version `1.6.1`. It appears to be fixed in `1.6.2`.